# PHP connecting to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, forms

I want to connect to sql server with php. I have a table of users but I can't connect the server.

Login.php

```
  <html>
  <form action='LoginAction.php' method='POST'>
  Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br/>
  Password: <input type='password' name='password'/><br/>
  <input type='submit' value='Login'/>
  </form>
  </html>
```

I tryed 2 codes to LoginAction.php

The First:

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  if ($username&&$password)
  {
      $connect = mysql_connect("myphpadmin.net", $username, $password, "my_db") or       die("Couldn't connect!");
      mysql_select_db("users") or die("Coulnd't find db!");
  }
  else
  {
      die("please fill in all fields.");
  }
?>
```

The second:

```
<?php
  $connection=mysqli_connect("example.com",$username, $password,"my_db");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection))
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Also, I created a table "users.sql" and tryed to put it in my code, and it's stull not working. Can you help me?

Thanks for helpers!

Edit: I think I will try do it with PDO as aldanux said, thanks for all!

Comment: do you connect to local host or remote host?

Comment: replace `"myphpadmin.net",` with `localhost`

Comment: Both your connection strings appear to be using totally different (and likely not accessible) servers.

Comment: He is connecting to another universe.

Comment: if you start to learning then learn better with PDO (PHP Data Objects) - [Tutorial how to connect to database with Mysqli/PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)

Comment: then you should use localhost insteadof myphpadmin.net

Comment: I tryed replace "myphpadmin.net" to "localhost" but it's not working...

Comment: Did anyone notice that he tries to login a user of his page as a mysql db user? I guess he wants to implement a costum login instead and use his correct db login data for `mysql_connect()`! (I don't think he wants to develop something like phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Christoph: yes, it's true. But as aldanux said I can use PDO..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this PHP

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if (isset($username) && isset($password))
{
    try {
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);

            // to close connection 
        $connection = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This one is working good.

I don't want to be silly but if I create a sql file in my computer(and not on localhost) can I connect it with this code? And if yeah, how?

Comment: I didn't get you exactly .
But using this script you can connect to server , for this change 
`localhost` to host name of server .

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe....

```
<html>

<form action='LoginAction.php' method='POST'>

Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br/>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'/><br/>
Database: <input type='text' name='database'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Login'/>

</form>

</html>
```

And the php....

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$database = $_POST['database'];

if (isset($username) && isset($password) && isset($database))
{

$connect = mysql_connect("myphpadmin.net", $username, $password, $database) or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("users") or die("Coulnd't find db!");

}
else
{

die("please fill in all fields.");

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your edit you mentioned PDO, here's an example !

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array(
    'host' => 'yourHost(i.e. localhost)',
    'username' => 'yourUsername',
    'password' => 'yourPassword',
    'dbname' => 'yourDBName'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';
               dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'],
                          $config['db']['username'],
                          $config['db']['password']);

?>
```

Your login situation would be something in the likes of this:

```
<?php
    include '../connection_file.php';

    $username= $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $select_query = "SELECT
                   username,
                   password
                FROM user
                WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";

    $get_user = $db->prepare($select_query);

    $get_user->execute(array(':username' => $username,
                             ':password' => $password));

    $countRows = $get_user->rowCount();

    if($countRows >= 1){
        //The user is logged in
        //echo "true" or header('yourLocation')
    }else{
        //The user doesn't exist
        //echo "true" or header('yourLocation')
    }

?>
```

I Hope this helped !

**EDIT**

Stupid mistake, maybe you want to encrypt the password, you can do so by doing:

```
$password = $_GET['password'];
$encrypt_password = md5($password);
//As you guessed "md5" encrypts the password ;)
```

Of course don't forget to also replace "$password" in your $get_user->execute(array) with $encrypt_password !

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("myphpadmin.net", $username, $password) or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die("Coulnd't find db!");
```